# Associate different column name to one Model + cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

how to get name of (UserTransactionType.name) with Transaction.who_pay_fee_1,2,3 fields.

'user_transaction_type_id' works well but how to get the rest of fields work :(

```
//Transaction Model
        public $belongsTo = array(
                'UserTransactionType' => array(
                    'className' => 'UserTransactionType',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_transaction_type_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
                ),

//UserTransactionType Model
public $hasMany = array(
        'Transaction' => array(
            'className' => 'Transaction',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_transaction_type_id',
            'dependent' => false,
))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people they like CakePhp :)
in Controller ->
get the list of 'UserTransactionType'
in View ->
after looping trough all the transactions; in Transaction Status column simply load the 'UserTransactionType'array and assign the number of array to $userTransactionTypes.

```
$userTransactionTypes[$transaction['Who_pay_fee_1']];
```

To be honest it was straight forward but needed a bit concentration :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code for your controller:

```
$this->UserTransactionType->find('all',array(
                                             'fields' => array('name'),
                                             'contain' => array('Transaction')
                                            )
                                 );
```

If Models are associated you can specify in `'contain'` which of them you want to get in the result.

If you want to have only some fields of related Model, you can determine them after `'Transaction'` in `'contain'` just like in the regular `find()` query:

```
'contain' => array('Transaction' => array('fields' => array('field_1',
                                                            'field_2') ))
```

But in your case, you don't need to specify fields, because by default you get all fields.

So no matter if you define or not fields "who_pay_fee_1,2,3" because if you use  `'contain'` by default you will get foreing_key - `user_transaction_type_id`.

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. but it should be  as simple as below question :)